# Foxpro form "stopping" work after report call

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have a form to call a report, the form contant btnPrint
In my "Print" button click, I call the report

btnPrint.click

```
REPORT FORM rpthocbong PREVIEW
```

After the button was clicked, the button "Print" is "flat-down" and cannot click again

Comment: Check what the report might be doing for any side-effects. Also, verify that any other code in the form (like in the `Activate`, `Deactivate` events or similar) isn't deactivating the button by mistake.

Comment: Remember that after report the alias of the report remains on eof()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this after your report form call?

```
this.enabled = .t.
```